# Export/Import Task Group

Tags: tfs, build-definition

We are using TFS 2017 update 2 on-premises.
We want to update our test environment with the build definitions from production. With an extension we could copy the build definitions https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.ExportImportBuildDefinition , but this does not export the task-group of the build definition.

Are there ways to export the task group and import it in another project or in my case in a different TFS server?

Comment: As I know there is a way to create task group manually https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/1498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality to export Task Groups is certainly present in VSTS. Although the documentation says that is is available in TFS 2017,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/task-groups

We haven't seen the References tab being added as of writing this answer. We are using TFS 2017 Update 2. I haven't seen it being added for TFS Update 3 either

Comment: This feature is available in TFS 2018.

Comment: yes, it is available in TFS 2018. However, the documentation link above mentions TFS 2017 / VSTS.

Comment: Thanks also found this documentation-link, but couldn't find in in TSF2017 either.
The documentation doesn't show an import button, but I assume it is there.

Comment: Found it on VSTS: it arrow pointing down (so next to refresh button)

Answer (score 1):

Task groups are stored at project level, and are not accessible outside the project scope. So Export/Import build definition extension can export/import task group in the same team project only.

Export/Import task group function as @Hamid mentioned is available in TFS 2018 and VSTS. You could consider upgrade to TFS 2018 to enjoy this new function.